# Checking status of website in Java

Tags: java, web

In Java, is there a standard library that permits checking the status of a website, i.e. whether or not the website is accessible?

If not, are there any third-party libraries that do the same thing?

Comment: Use an `URLConnection`, get an `InputStream` and try to read. If it times out, your website is not accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the below thing, where you get response as `200` i.e. accessible else not accessable

```
public static boolean isAccessable(String url, int timeout) {
    url = url.replaceFirst("https", "http"); // Otherwise an exception may
                                                // be thrown on invalid SSL
                                                // certificates.

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != 200) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open a connection to the URL and retrieve the response code and (optionally) content:

```
    public static boolean isSiteUp(URL site) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) site.openConnection();
            conn.getContent();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException tout) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            // You may decide on more specific behaviour...
            return false;
        }
      }
```

What response codes you consider to mean that the site is "up" and "down" will depend slightly on your application. (If you get a "content forbidden" response, does that mean that the site is "up" for your purposes?) Unless the site actually returns a code to say "I am down", then you need to make a decision as to whether, say, a timeout represents the site actually being down or you having a local firewall issue etc. But nonetheless, some variant of the above should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HTTP library like https://hc.apache.org/ make a request and check the return code

Comment: No need to introduce a library for that. See [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jersey client (plenty of examples such as http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/)

or you can use org.apache.http.client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any JAVA library which can make http call. Two such popular java libraries are **HttpClient** and **URLConnection**.

So you just need to get status of the url using either of above libraries. If status is 200 then URL is up.

If you want to do this in any unix based machine then **curl** utility is very easy to know the status. Just do a man on curl you will get all options.